# angular js adding the value of two functions in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two functions on my `$scope`: `getTotal1()` and `getTotal2()`.

When I do:

```
<div>{{getTotal1() || 0}}</div> <!-- it works -->
<div>{{getTotal2() || 0}}</div> <!-- it also works -->
<div>Grant total: {{getTotal1() + getTotal2() || 0}} <!-- this is not working -->
```

I want to know what am i doing wrong here ? why this won't work ?

**Edit**
both of these functions return a positive integer 0 and greater

Comment: what is in console? or you just get wrong results?

Comment: I know literally nothing about angularjs... but if I were to guess, I'd say that the `+` in the 3rd line means that the left hand side is always valid, independent of what the two functions return, so will never get to the 0

Comment: nope just returns 0 no error in console

Comment: common guys why to vote negative whats wrong with this question ?

Comment: Can you try this ternary condition ? `{{(getTotal1() + getTotal2() != 0 ? getTotal1() + getTotal2() : 0)}}`

Comment: Angularjs completely suppresses a lot of messages that occur within `{{ ... }}`.  Do you want this associativity? `{{(getTotal1() + getTotal2() )|| 0 }}` ?

Comment: what is getTotal1() and getTotal2() returning?

Comment: Yes it misses a bit of details right here ! Please provide your relevant controller code associated.

Comment: How can we possibly tell if you only provide  code snippet and not enough relevant code for anyone to see why. `is not working` is not a proper problem description either

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thank you @charlietfl i will post my next question as per the guidelines.

Comment: If both functions are returning a number, why do you need to add ` || 0` to the expression? Just add the two values.

Comment: you can also fix this one if you still need help

Comment: Try {{(getTotal1() || 0) + (getTotal2() || 0)}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `plunker` with your example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/aPOQusSigbpOeuTjK7YG?p=preview

Could you tell me what is wrong there?

It seems to work!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was my fault and the question was a bit ambiguous with not enough details. What i was doing was generating dynamic fields and these two methods were actually getting the numbers form those dynamically generated fields so when a dynamically generated field has no value it was returning a NaN, so i just put a condition there if (isNaN(aField)) aField = 0; SO THE PROBLEM was in some cases these functions were not returning a number